# Почему не работает перевод плагина?

Tags: php, wordpress

Использую данный код в плагине для перевода, но перевод не работает.

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'stock_alert_init' );
function stock_alert_init(){
    $locale = is_admin() && function_exists('get_user_locale') ? get_user_locale() : get_locale();
    $locale = apply_filters('plugin_locale', $locale, 'woocommerce-product-stock-alert');
    load_textdomain('woocommerce-product-stock-alert', WP_LANG_DIR . '/woocommerce-product-stock-alert/woocommerce-product-stock-alert-' . $locale . '.mo');
    load_plugin_textdomain('woocommerce-product-stock-alert', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/');
}
```

В папке `/languages` находятся такие файлы перевода:
woocommerce-product-stock-alert-ua.po
woocommerce-product-stock-alert-ua.mo
woocommerce-product-stock-alert-en_US.po
woocommerce-product-stock-alert-en_US.mo
Язык в админке украинский `ua`
Как настроить перевод?

Comment: Для данной задачи есть плагин Loco Translate - https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/

Comment: @Vitaliy Antal, а почему не работает вышеприведённый код?

Comment: В каком файле находится этот код?

Comment: @KAGG Design в основном файле плагина, где прописано `Plugin Name:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файлы должны иметь суффикс uk, не ua. Потому что украинская локаль называется uk: https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/teams/#all